# Numerical and analytical equation solving in python or matlab

Tags: python, matlab, numerical-methods, equation-solving

Let's suppose that I have two transcendental functions `f(x, y) = 0` and `g(a, b) = 0`.

a and b depend on y, so if I could solve the first equation analytically for y, `y = f(x)`, I could have the second function depending only on x and thus solving it numerically.

I prefer to use python, but if matlab is able to handle this is ok for me.

Is there a way to solve analytically trascendent functions for a variable with python/matlab? Taylor is fine too, as long as I can choose the order of approximation.

Comment: not python related, and more in general off topic on Stack Overflow

Comment: In general, no. In many specific cases, yes. Can you share the function / family of functions you are considering?

Comment: @fferri yes I had thought about that, but this is actually a problem hard to solve without a calculator. Moreover, in the end, I will have to write the algorithm down; so for me it's also a programming problem. You've got a point anyway.

Comment: @HughBothwell `k*tan(y) + j*tan(arcsin(sin(y)/x)) = const.` and I need to have `y = f(x)`

Comment: I feel that for this kind of problem you may have better luck on http://math.stackexchange.com/ (you can talk about programming too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running this through Sympy like so:

```
import sympy

j, k, m, x, y = sympy.symbols("j k m x y")
eq = sympy.Eq(k * sympy.tan(y) + j * sympy.tan(sympy.asin(sympy.sin(y) / x)), m)
eq.simplify()
```

which turned your equation into

```
Eq(m, j*sin(y)/(x*sqrt(1 - sin(y)**2/x**2)) + k*tan(y))
```

which, after a bit more poking, gives us

```
k * tan(y) + j * sin(y) / sqrt(x**2 - sin(y)**2) == m
```

We can find an expression for `x(y)` like

```
sympy.solve(eq, x)
```

which returns

```
[-sqrt(j**2*sin(y)**2/(k*tan(y) - m)**2 + sin(y)**2),
 sqrt(j**2*sin(y)**2/(k*tan(y) - m)**2 + sin(y)**2)]
```

but an analytic solution for `y(x)` fails.